# Connect Android device to WiFi printer to take print programatically

Tags: android, printing

I want to print my pdf document by my Android phone using wifi printer. As far of my search from 4.4 we can able to use android printer manager but my application need to support from 4.0. please give me a suggestion about it is possible to connect our Device to wifi printer or send our document for printing. I hope, I will get best answer or any suggestion from your side as soon as possible.

Comment: Step #1: Walk over to the printer. Step #2: Examine the front of the printer, looking for a manufacturer name or logo. Step #3: Use a search engine to try to find out if that printer manufacturer has Android printing support, and if so, for what versions of Android. Even on Android 4.4, you need the app equivalent of a printer driver to work with a printer, and anything prior to Android 4.4 is  up to the printer manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can't we make the app which support all the printer ??

Comment: On 4.4 and higher, you can through Android's printing framework, but the *device* still needs a driver. On 4.3 and below, Android has no knowledge of printing.

Comment: Thank you for your great time, may i know which will be great solution to print the pdf from android 4+ devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had used [this](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/mobile/android/) in one of my projects

So go through this and i hope you will get an idea.It supports with Bluetooth, Wi-Fi (Infrastructure mode), USB. and the supported formats are

```
PDF: pdf
Image: bmp, jpg, png
Print data: prn
```

Comment: Note that this is for Brother brand printers.

Comment: Link is dead it seems, can you check it again

Comment: when ever i tried to open it says web page not open

Comment: Brother brand printers SDK is paid one or free ?